# Software Performance Testing tools

Tags: load-testing, functional

This question might come as very broad and opinion based, but for the sake of my inexperience in Software performance testing, I will risk the possible downvoting.

What are some good tools with which I can test my C# WPF applications' performance? I want something I can use for the long run, something that can actually tell me whether my software is fast or not, if it's efficient or not.

In the best case, it will also analyze my code in depth about its maintainability, maybe reusability and how easy it is to read, and basically, overall code quality.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468572/how-to-profile-wpf-4-5-ui-performance probably it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, it is actually, will take a look at it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

- Jmeter
- WebLOAD
- LoadUI
- NG Pro
- SmartMeter.io
- Tricentis
- Flood
- LoadView
- LoadRunner
- Appvance
- NeoLoad
- LoadComplete
- WAPT
- Loadster
- LoadImpact
- Rational Performance Tester
- Testing Anywhere
- OpenSTA
- QEngine (ManageEngine)
- Loadstorm
- CloudTest
- Httperf